# How to use well-typed Path in some record

Tags: haskell, path

I have some record where should be multiple paths/files. Let's suppose I want to use [Path](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-0.6.1/docs/Path.html) type for them and they can be relative and absolute in the same time. I can do:

```
data SomeRecord = SomeRecord {
  p1 :: forall a. Path a Dir
 ,p2 :: forall a. Path a Dir
 , ...
}
```

but how to assign some concrete `Path` to p1, p2, pN when I'll get error about rigid type error. Also I'll need to add different constraints to these p1, p2 declarations (for example, Show...). Another way is:

```
data SomeRecord a b c d e ... z = SomeRecord {
  p1  :: Path a Dir
 ,p2  :: Path b Dir
 ...
 ,p26 :: Path z Dir
}
```

which:

- extracts all type parameters to `SomeRecord`
- usage of several `SomeRecord` in one list now is impossible, so I'll need again to add `forall` clauses for such lists and to play with constraints

What is the canonical way to do it? To avoid well-typed `Path` in such context? If it is, does it mean that such types (like `Path`) are not good for multiple fields in records?

Comment: The point of `path` is that you care about whether or not a path is relative or absolute. If you don't, then don't use it (although most of the time you probably do care, I really can't think of many scenarios where you genuinely want a mix of relative and absolute paths)

Comment: Use-case is: I retrieve from some DB path which is Dir, but it can be relative or absolute. So, if I want more special type than FilePath/Text I need some info that it's a dir and not file, so I've remembered that `Path` keeps such information (`Dir`/`File`) to distinguish files from dirs. But No type `Path {Dir|File}` there. And if i need it, I get this useless parameter

Comment: May be it's even theoretical question: if you have phantom type `T a b c d e` and you need some subtype like `T a b e` in some record with a lot of such fields, what is the most good solution (to avoid boilerplate code and similar problems)?

Comment: Note that I have a fork of path, with `SomeBase` that does what you are looking for, https://mstksg.github.io/path/Path-Posix.html#t:SomeBase .  It's essentially @bergey's answer.  The fork is here https://github.com/mstksg/path/tree/somebase

Comment: @JustinL. would you explain what is the difference from the original Path?

Comment: @Paul-AG it's essentially just an Either between the two paths.

`type SomeBase a = Either (Path Abs a) (Path Rel a)`

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely want to use `Path`, you can define each field as

`p1 :: Either (Path Rel Dir) (Path Abs Dir)`.

I'd be inclined to define my own `newtype Dir = Dir String` instead, and move the code to check which it is to the use sites.  Or else to normalize paths sooner.